# cannot satisfy `_: Runnable<dyn A, Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn A>>>>>`

Tags: rust

I designed a trait that can run things that are `Lockable`, that is, can be locked to produce `Option<T>`, and I implemented it for `Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<T>>>>`

```
use std::sync::{LockResult, PoisonError, MutexGuard, Arc, Mutex};

pub type LockableArc<T: ?Sized> = Arc<Mutex<Option<T>>>;

pub struct MutexGuardOptionRef<'a, T: ?Sized> {
    pub mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>>,
}

pub trait LockableOption<T: ?Sized>: Clone + Send {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>>;
}

pub trait Runnable<R: ?Sized, T: LockableOption<R> + Clone + Send + ?Sized> {
    fn run(s: T) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

impl<T: ?Sized + Send> LockableOption<T> for LockableArc<Box<T>> {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

pub trait A: Send{}

pub struct S{}

impl A for S{}

impl<R: A, T: LockableOption<R> + Clone + Send + 'static> Runnable<R, T>
    for S
{
    fn run(arc_rtsp: T) -> Result<(), ()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r: LockableArc<Box<dyn A>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Box::new(S{}))));
    Runnable::run(r.clone());
    //Runnable::<dyn A, LockableArc<Box<dyn A>>>::run(r.clone());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28f71dbd3bf9cd900d8c2fc6af63b432)

Error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:39:5
   |
14 |     fn run(s: T) -> Result<(), ()>;
   |     ------------------------------- required by `Runnable::run`
...
39 |     Runnable::run(r.clone());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: Runnable<dyn A, Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn A>>>>>`
```

I don't understand this error. First because I don't know what `'_` is. It looks like it's the type passed to run as the only argument. So I tried to force the type:

```
Runnable::<dyn A, LockableArc<Box<dyn A>>>::run(r.clone());
```

but I get the same error. What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Runnable` is a trait, so `Runnable::run` does not know which implementation of that trait to use.  Use `S::run` instead.
2. `S::run` won't work because its implementation of `Runnable` requires that `R: A` whereas here `R` is `dyn A`.  Just restrict `R: ?Sized` instead and you should be fine.

Therefore ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fca31622d50eed2a3c28bfb397f493a6)):

```
use std::sync::{LockResult, PoisonError, MutexGuard, Arc, Mutex};

pub type LockableArc<T: ?Sized> = Arc<Mutex<Option<T>>>;

pub struct MutexGuardOptionRef<'a, T: ?Sized> {
    pub mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>>,
}

pub trait LockableOption<T: ?Sized>: Clone + Send {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>>;
}

pub trait Runnable<R: ?Sized, T: LockableOption<R> + Clone + Send + ?Sized> {
    fn run(s: T) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

impl<T: ?Sized + Send> LockableOption<T> for LockableArc<Box<T>> {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

pub trait A: Send{}

pub struct S{}

impl A for S{}

impl<R: ?Sized, T: LockableOption<R> + Clone + Send + 'static> Runnable<R, T>
    for S
{
    fn run(arc_rtsp: T) -> Result<(), ()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r: LockableArc<Box<dyn A>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Box::new(S{}))));
    S::run(r.clone());
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know which `dyn A` exists inside of `r`? In this case it was `S`, but what if it's `SS: dyn A`? It's kinda strange that I need one specific concrete type to run a trait object. Isn't there a way to do this such that I just use `Runnable::run`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: you don’t have a trait object though… if `run` was a *method* (ie with a `self` parameter) rather than an *associated function*, and you had something `dyn Runnable` then you would be able to invoke `.run()` on that something without knowing its concrete type.  But that’s a long way from what you have here.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: Let’s put it another way… suppose you implement `Runnable` for another type `SS` like you suggest: this time returning `Err(())`.  If you could call `Runnable::run()`, should you get the `Ok(())` from `S`, the `Err(())` from `SS`, or something else?!

Comment: Indeed, that's the problem. I wanted to be able to run things that are lockable, and when locked, return `Box<T>`. The example here is `Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<T>>>>`, but it could be anything that returns `Option<T>` in `lock()`. However, I cannot see how it would be made if `fn run(&self)`, how should I specify that the `self: Self` should implement `LockableOption`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: what do you mean “run” them?  Where is the code that does that?

Comment: by `run` I mean calling `run` on something, which would lock itself and start running code on its own thread. So, the idea is that anything that implements `LockableOption` should have a `run(&self)` method that when called, enters a while loop on its own thread, where `self.lock()` is called periodically to access the object. An example would be `LockableArc<T> = Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<T>>>>`, which would have an `run(&self)` method that when called would clone `self`, then begin a `loop{self.clone.lock().unwrap().unwrap().do_something(); sleep()}`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: Then I guess instead of implementing `Runnable` for `S`, you're probably after a blanket implementation of it for anything that implements `LockableOption`—essentially `impl<L, T> Runnable for L where L: LockableOption<T>`, except that won't work because parameter `T` is unconstrained; perhaps the easiest solution is to add a parameter `T` to `Runnable`.  See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=22d1e4e0390c156dd4a6cf096a050d79).

Comment: Nice, but how am I going to implement different `run` functions for each struct? For example, `S: A` would have its own implementation, as well as `SS: A` and `SSS: A`, etc. Or do you mean I can implement it for different `L`? For example `impl<L: LockableOption<S>> Runnable<S> for L` and `impl<L: LockableOption<SS>, SS> Runnable<SS> for L` etc?

Comment: I still don't see how to implement for each struct that implements `A`, for example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f2e750800dd8dd00322312e0e633beae (I also added a little example on how it would run things)

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: in what way(s) could the implementation for `SS` differ?

Comment: Yes, I think I didn't make it very clear. Let's say I'll have a Runnable for each trait, so `Runnable<T>`, and I want `run` to receive a `dyn LockableOption<T>`. Here's a clear example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ca14795ac61c9f2eaa0be9ae55d38ca0 with the problem that `Box<dyn LockableOption<>>` is not `Clone`, so I cannot lock it on its own thread