# note: cannot satisfy `_: DecoderRunnable<u8>`

Tags: rust

On this simple sketch I made, I'm trying to do use a trait called `Runnable` to run an `Arc<dyn LockableOption<T>>`:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, LockResult, Mutex, MutexGuard, PoisonError};

pub type LockableArc<T> = Arc<Mutex<Option<T>>>;

pub struct MutexGuardOptionRef<'a, T: ?Sized> {
    pub mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>>,
}

pub trait LockableOption<T: ?Sized>: Send + Sync {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>>;
}

impl<T: ?Sized + Send> LockableOption<T> for LockableArc<Box<T>> {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

pub trait Decoder<T>: Send {
}

pub struct FfmpegDecoder<T> {
    x: T,
}

impl<T: 'static + Send> Decoder<T> for FfmpegDecoder<T> {
}

trait DecoderRunnable<T> {
    fn run(s: Arc<dyn LockableOption<dyn Decoder<T>>>);
}

impl<T: 'static + Send> DecoderRunnable<T> for FfmpegDecoder<T> {
    fn run(s_lockable: Arc<dyn LockableOption<dyn Decoder<T>>>) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r: LockableArc<Box<dyn Decoder<u8>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Box::new(FfmpegDecoder{x: 0u8}))));
    let rr: Arc<dyn LockableOption<dyn Decoder<u8>>> = Arc::new(r);
    DecoderRunnable::<u8>::run(rr.clone());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19062310ba6e4e12b5b9aca4f39ec051)

I get the error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:42:5
   |
30 |     fn run(s: Arc<dyn LockableOption<dyn Decoder<T>>>);
   |     --------------------------------------------------- required by `DecoderRunnable::run`
...
42 |     DecoderRunnable::<u8>::run(rr.clone());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: DecoderRunnable<u8>`
```

which I don't get. Why anything here should satisfy `DecoderRunnable`? `DecoderRunnable` is a trait that has a `run` function that expects `Arc<dyn LockableOption<dyn Decoder<T>>>` and I'm passing `rr` which is exactly that.

Comment: how does this differ from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68241551/cannot-satisfy-runnabledyn-a-arcmutexoptionboxdyn-a?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traits have to be implemented types so the compiler can figure out which implementation to run. In your example, `DecoderRunnable` is only implemented for `FfmpegDecoder<T>` and you're trying to call it on an `Arc<dyn LockableOption<dyn Decoder<u8>>>`, which has no implementation.

You can always specify which implementation needs to be called by using this syntax:

```rust
<FfmpegDecoder<u8> as DecoderRunnable::<u8>>::run(rr);
```

Although it doesn't seem like what you're trying to do . It's not clear what you're trying to abstract, since you also have the decoder deeply nested inside `LockableArc<T>`.

If you just want to add convenience methods to `LockableArc<Box<dyn Decoder<u8>>>`, you can add an impl block for `Arc<dyn ...>` , and make the `run` method take `&self` instead of `Arc<dyn ...>` as its first parameter.

Comment: Indeed. It's almost that, but I'd like to use `DecoderRunnable::<u8>::run(rr.clone());` and let it dynamically dispatch the call to the right implementation. In this case, `FfmpegDecoder::run`. Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: What's the conceptual between `Decoder<T>` and `DecoderRunnable<T>` ? If you were holding a `dyn DecoderRunnable<u8>` this would be feasible, but you're holding a `dyn Decoder<u8>` instead. You could define `Decoder<T>` as a supertrait for `Decoder<T>` and change it to `dyn DecoderRunnable<u8>` instead